# Is there a way to run MPEG-TS stream over RTSP?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, mpeg2-ts

I'm trying to measure latency from the moment a frame was captured, till the time I display it.

In order to do so, I need to make sure I send the PTS value with the captured frame timestamp (with MPEG-TS over UDP). This is how I do it (and it works good!!):

ffmpeg -re -f v4l2 -copyts -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -intra -f mpegts -mpegts_copyts 1 udp://192.168.10.199:1234

Later, I've a short script that reads the PTS, do some calculations, and prints the latency while playing the video on real-time.

**Is there a way to do the same over RTSP** (I know I can do it over RTP...) **?**

Comment: PTS is for each video frames, if you need to support if over RTSP , too much unnecessary message flow will happen. its not a practical solution.

Comment: But when I run: 
ffprobe -i rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -show_frames, I do see the PTS of each frame. 
Why is that ?

Comment: PTS - presentation timestamp (PTS) -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_timestamp

Comment: I think I still missing something from the link you have shared. Do you have a quote from the link that explains why I see the PTS of each frame when streaming over RTSP ? (cause from that I understand, you are saying RTSP doesn't support PTS. Please correct me if I miss understood you)

Comment: please check the rfc for rtsp : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7826